# Breakpoints not being hit when debugging a DirectShow push filter with Chrome as the host process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, directshow, breakpoints

I am using the pure C# DirectShow push filter called VirtualCam from this open source project/article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp

I want to debug it in Visual Studio 2013 so I set the *external program* in the Debug settings to Chrome and load a web page that enumerates and can switch between the detected DirectShow video push filters on the system.  However.  None of my breakpoints are being hit, and I've got one on nearly every method in the filter, especially the format checking and negotiation calls.

The breakpoints are fully active and I am not getting the error message that the push filter's DLL image doesn't match the source when I hover over a breakpoint icon.  But they're not getting hit either.   This technique used to work fine when I was doing DirectShow filter work with Delphi and DSPack.  Why is it not working for me with C# and VirtualCam?

**UPDATE**: Dirk below makes a very good point about Chrome's multi-process infrastructure being the root problem.  If anyone has an idea on how to debug given such a context, please let me know.

Comment: Are you debugging the right chrome process? Keep in mind that chrome uses a multi-process architecture and your plugin might not run in the process that started chrome.

Comment: @Dirk That's a really good point.

Comment: Supposedly you can switch Chrome to use less processes at least for the time you debug the filters (it is known to spawn new processes not only when it's absolutely needed, but instead to isolate parts one from another).

Comment: @RomanR But wouldn't I have to have exactly one process?  If it's just less processes I would assume there's still the chance that the process that loads the filter isn't the one I launched from the IDE as the debug target and therefore my breakpoints still won't get hit.

Comment: Ideally, it would be one process. Or maybe two, to be able to make 32/64 switch